# Como buscar solo por un tipo de dato en DataTable en Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo un DataTable en Jquery y quisiera saber si es posible que el buscador que trae incorporado me permita buscar solo por **1** tipo de dato.

Lo que me gustaría hacer es que el dato a buscar sea el **email.**

Y si se escribe cualquier cosa que no sea el **email** no debería mostrar **nada.** Aunque coincida el valor con alguna columna, pero mientras no sea el email no debería funcionar.

Además debe ser **exacto**, es decir, el email completo, porque pueden haber muchos email que los primeros caracteres sean idénticos, o de dominio distinto, como por ejemplo:

- roberto@gmail.com
- roberto432@gmail.com
- roberto@yahoo.cl

Y el buscador debería poder diferenciar el uno con el otro, ya que no son iguales.

El problema es que no se muy bien como controlar la información a buscar en un datatable, para poder buscar por email.

Dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#Mytable').DataTable({
        language:{
            sProcessing: "Procesando...",
            sLengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ Registros",
            sZeroRecords: "No se encontraron resultados relacionados",
            sEmptyTable: "No hay ningún dato disponible para esta tabla",
            sInfo: "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros.",
            sInfoEmpty: "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            sInfoFiltered: "(Filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            sSearch: "Buscar:",
            sInfoThousands: ",",
            sLoadingRecords: "Cargando...",
            oPaginate: {
                sFirst: "Primero",
                sLast: "Último",
                sNext: "Siguiente",
                sPrevious: "Anterior"
            },
            oAria: {
                sSortAscending: ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                sSortDescending: ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
table tbody tr td{
  text-align: center;
}
body{

  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<table id="Mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>NOMBRE</th>
      <th>DIRECCION</th>
      <th>EMAIL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pedro Muñoz</td>
      <td>Calle Los Arbolitos #321</td>
      <td>pedro@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Juan Castro</td>
      <td>Avenida Central Edificio - El Alto P.7 #301</td>
      <td>juan@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Roberto Riquelme</td>
      <td>Calle La estrecha #432</td>
      <td>roberto@yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Alicia Godoy</td>
      <td>Avenida La Grande Edificio El Gigante P12 #432</td>
      <td>alice121@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Alicia Fernandez</td>
      <td>Avenida La Grande Edificio El Gigante P12 #432</td>
      <td>alice121@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Jimena Lagos</td>
      <td>Calle La tierra #123</td>
      <td>Jime6879@outlook.com</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Camilo Rios</td>
      <td>Calle La Laguna #543</td>
      <td>CamiloT@yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Pedro Paredez</td>
      <td>Avenida Predera Verde Edificio El Rascacielo P15 #654</td>
      <td>pedroPrz543@outlook.com</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Camila Reyes</td>
      <td>Calle Los Sentidos Av. El Pensamiento #321</td>
      <td>cami798@outlook.com</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Camila Godoy</td>
      <td>Avenida El Farol - Calle 213 n°432</td>
      <td>camy768@yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Antonio Reyes</td>
      <td>Calle El Gato - #748</td>
      <td>anton789@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Antonia Reyes</td>
      <td>Calle El Gato - #748</td>
      <td>anto_68@yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un este enlace donde se esta filtrando por el campo mail.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbdhL346/

Lo que estamos haciendo es que cada vez que exista un evento en nuestro input. Obtenemos los campos de la columna 3, buscamos en esos campos contra el valor del input y pintamos de nuevo la tabla.

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().bind('keyup', function() {
  table.column( 3).search( this.value ).draw();
});
```

Obtención de una columna
https://datatables.net/reference/api/column()

Busqueda de datos en un la tabla
https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

Pintamos de nuevo nuestra tabla
https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Te adjunto este enlace de datatables donde se esta realizando un filtro por columna, que te puede resultar útil.

https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Un saludo!

Comment: para que tu respuesta se considere como válida debes colocar los ejemplos aquí, pues solo poner enlaces se considera de baja calidad ya que si dejan de estar disponibles, la respuesta deja de ser útil

Comment: Di a guardar sin querer, la respuesta esta editada. @shadow

Comment: @JairoRoderoVilla. Gracias por responder, mira estuve probando y el DataTable igual me busca si escribo algo que no sea el email, cuando el buscador no debería funcionar si escribo algo que no sea el email.

Comment: @M4uriXD Hola no comprendo, muy bien la duda que tienes. Por lo que te entiendo, tu quieres que la tabla busque por el campo mail, pero si metes otro campo que no actue, es decir, que la tabla no se filtre. Ahora bien como sabe el input que tu quieres meter un mail o no? Como mucho lo único que se me ocurre es que, mediante un patrón de email en javascript entre o no al código que filtra la tabla. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: @M4uriXD si esta filtrando bien la columna de email, si agregas una fila adicional en donde los valores de toda la fila no se parescan veras que si filtra correctamente, ahora cabe recalcal que el `search( this.value )` realiza un filtrado muy parecido a un `like %%` de sql, quizas hay esta el inconveniente. Como te dicen en los comentarios tendras que utilizar algun patron de email.

Comment: Dice que si está filtrando bien, pero _(puede que me equivoque)_ creo que no lo está completamente, lo que busco es que al escribir el email me muestre solo ese email con sus datos, por ejemplo: En la pregunta escribí varios email, con solo escribir **roberto**, debería mostrar los 2 robertos, gmail.com e yahoo.com y no mostrar **roberto432-gmail.com**. A eso me refiero con buscar por el email, si se puede.

Comment: @M4uriXD Puedes probar esto para ver si es lo que necesitas?  `table.column( 3).search( this.value + '@' ).draw();`

Comment: @M4uriXD como te comente el `search( this.value )` realiza un filtrado muy parecido a un `like %%` de sql, por lo tanto es como si realizaras una like asi: `like %roberto%` y buscara todo lo que contenga la palabra roberto.

Comment: Entiendo entonces descarto lo ultimo que dije, sobre lo otro de _inhabilitar_ el filtro si se escribe algo que no sea el correo. Es posible de lograr?